# PhpStorm on Mac Subversion could not saving settings, please restart PhpStorm

Tags: macos, svn, phpstorm

This is going to be an answer I discovered the hard way, and specific to this case scenario. I use

```
PhpStorm 2022.2
Build #PS-222.3345.135, built on July 28, 2022
```

on my Macbook Pro which is running Mac OS Monterey Version 12.15.

I was having difficulties with the Subversion plugin attempting to install, but ultimately returning the error "Could not save settings, restart PhpStorm". This error was caused by a permissions issue in Mac OS Monterey with the projects `.svn` (hidden file with subversion config for those who don't know).

While perhaps not the most gracious fix, I simply right clicked the project directory, went to permissions, and opened them up, and applied to enclosed items. Afterwards svn was working perfectly like it was prior to me updating my machine.

Hopefully this helps someone, spent two hours on this dumb issue. lmao

Answer (score 1):

While perhaps not the most gracious fix, I simply right clicked the project directory, went to permissions, and opened them up, and applied to enclosed items. Afterwards svn was working perfectly like it was prior to me updating my machine.

Hopefully this helsp someone, spent two hours on this dumb issue. lmao